# Android - webview opens extra activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, webview

I have a android app, in which the main activity calls a function from a external library, which then opens a webview if neccesary.

Opening the webview is no problem. My problem start when people/users close the webview. It appears that the webview (I think, I am not sure though) has opened an extra activity or something on top of the original app that called the external library.

Now users have to close 2 windows, before they can continue in the original app.

Does anyone have experience with this, or knows what's happening here?

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    private final String appKey = "Android.Lib.Test";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        externalLib.Initialize(this, getIntent(), appKey);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**External Lib**

```
public class externalLib
{
    private static final String TAG = "externalLib";
    private static int messageId;

    public static void Initialize(Context context, Intent intent, String newAppKey)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "initializing");

        APPKEY = newAppKey;

        if(intent.hasExtra("url"))
        {
            if(intent.getExtras().getString("url") != null)
            {
                Intent webViewIntent = new Intent(context, externalLibWebView.class);
                webViewIntent.putExtra("url", intent.getExtras().getString("url"));
                context.startActivity(webViewIntent);
            }
        }

        if(intent.hasExtra("messageId"))
        {
            messageId = intent.getExtras().getInt("messageId");
            Log.e(TAG, "messageId: " + messageId);
        }
        else
        {
            messageId = 0;
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: may be the web view is getting redirected to some other URL and first back is getting consumed by the web view itself. I had this problem while integrating some payment library...

Comment: I am not sure I understand you at the "first back" part. How did you solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the problems was. I wanted the webview to load the url, but instead, the browser was opened leaving the webview empty and thus "creating" the extra acitvity. Now the webview loads the url.